# Powershell Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_PhysicalMemory returns answer in parts

Tags: powershell

```
ForEach ($servername in $server)
{
Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $servername.ItemArray[0]  -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object PSComputerName ,@{Name="GB";Expression={$_.Capacity/1GB}} 
}
```

I want a list on all my servers total RAM for each machine, and this code above work BUT not all the way. The answer comes back like this:

```
PSComputerName GB 
-------------- --
Server1        16
Server1        16
Server1        16
Server1        16
Server2         4
Server3         8
Server4        16
Server4        16
Server4        16
Server4         8
Server5        16
```

and so on......

But why are the total divided in 4 parts for **Server1** 16x4, the total is 64 GB. 8 CPU machine. **Server4** has a total of 56 GB and 6 CPU. All servers are virtual. vmWare

Why cant it just return 64GB or 56 GB? A one and two processor machine returns as ONE row (see Server5.) I've have just changed the names for the servers.
There must be some very simple answer and I've tried to google almost every page with Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_PhysicalMemory included but can find any good explanation.

Hope someone can explain what I dont think about. And perhaps how the change the code.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, CIM_PhysicalMemory gives you the information per memory module. Server 1 has 4 modules with 16GB each = total: 64GB. So you need to sum those values, e.g.:

```
(get-ciminstance -Query "select capacity from CIM_PhysicalMemory" | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum / 1GB
```

You could also query Win32_Computersystem, there you get the total size:

```
(Get-CimInstance -query "select totalphysicalmemory from Win32_Computersystem").TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Putting this together:

```
#$result will contain a object foreach server containing the attributes name and totalmemory
$result = @(
    ForEach ($servername in $server) {
        $totalMemory = (get-ciminstance -Query "select capacity from CIM_PhysicalMemory" -computername $servername | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum / 1GB
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name=$servername
            totalMemory=$totalMemory
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: I'm getting there. Greenhorn on PS. How do I add the individual servername to a column like above? '$servername,((get-ciminstance -Query "select capacity from CIM_PhysicalMemory" -ComputerName $servername.ItemArray[0] | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum / 1GB) ' gives the info in just one colum'. What I trying to do is the to insert the info in a database with '| Write-SqlTableData'

Comment: `$result = @(
    ForEach ($servername in $server) {
        $totalMemory = (get-ciminstance -Query "select capacity from CIM_PhysicalMemory" -computername $servername.ItemArray[0] | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum / 1GB
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name=$servername.ItemArray[0]
            totalMemory=$totalMemory
        }
    }
)` Some adjustments and it did the trick!! Many thanks.